# Silverstripe - Best way to make a module extend from custom page type

Tags: php, silverstripe, extends

My site structure is all custom page types with a single parent page the extends from Page.php.

```
class CustomPage extends Page {}

class  Custom_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    //load all javascript/css for entire site here etc
}


class SomeClass extends CustomPage {}

class SomeClass_Controller extends Custom_Controller
{
    // etc etc you get the point. 
}
```

Every other page in the site now extends from CustomPage and Custom_Controller respectively. Page.php is pretty much empty.

Now the problem comes when using modules that are not written internally. The Blog* module for example will not inherit the javascripts/css/functions defined in the new base class Custom_Controller as it is set to extend Page_Controller.

What is the ideal method here for basically making Blog_Controller extend Custom_Controller without modifying the Blog module?

*Blog module is just an example. this applies to all modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to the direct question

`What is the ideal method here for basically making Blog_Controller extend Custom_Controller without modifying the Blog module?`

is that it's not technically possible to do. Effectively you've got two options;

1. Make your changes to the Page/Page_Controller classes directly
2. Inherit Page/Page_Controller in your custom page types, but rather than modifying Page directly, use an extension that is bound to Page to provide the custom behaviour for all sub-page types. For the specific case of providing custom `init()` behaviour, you'll want a custom extension that extends the `Extension` class, and is bound to Page_Controller

Check into [the extension documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/extending/extensions/) for a bit more information

Comment: Unfortunately option one is impossible due to our environment, and option two didn't seem to work either. I've never had problems adding getter methods to controllers via extensions but not having any luck with init() being in an extension. However what has seemed to work is subclassing Blog_Controller and copying in the required functions - this however isn't a very elegant solution...

Comment: For the extension, the method you need to define is `onBeforeInit()` or `onAfterInit()` (not init() itself)

Comment: Further adding to Marcus' advice - It seems in order for onAfter/BeforeInit to load requirements you need to clear what has been previously loaded first with Requirements::clear(). I'm not sure if this is unique to my environment or how I load but yeah...